# Record mywebsite.com link with query in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Tags: ios, safari, url-scheme, whitelist, info-plist

My iOS 11.0+ app is trying to open a URL of the following format, where DATANAME1, DATANAME2, USERNAME vary depending upon the user looking at different data:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/Topic.html?topic=DATANAME1-USERNAME-DATANAME2
```

However, the command 'canOpenURL' I use before calling this link returns false. I believe this is due to not having whitelisted this link.
Consider that any html page within mywebiste.com (for example: http://www.mywebsite.com/Help.html) can instead be opened without any issue.

Questions:

1. Since I cannot whitelist every possible combination of USERNAME, DATANAME1, DATANAME2 obviously, is there a way to whitelist the link under the key LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist?
2. Do I need to add a URLScheme (under Info->URL Types) as well? What would be the right string to add in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use canOpenUrl for http urls. Just open it. CanOpenUrl is to determine if there is an app installed that responds to a particular app URL scheme.

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. I used canOpenURL since OpenURL was not working so I needed to check whether the app could actually open that URL with a query inside it, which turned up it could not apparently. This fact triggered my question here.

Comment: `canOpenURL` indicates whether there is an app that will respond to a particular app url scheme.  That doesn't really apply to `http` as the url scheme.  Perhaps you want to look at reachability to determine if the device has internet connectivity?

Comment: In my understanding canOpenURL tells you whether the link can be opened or not via an app. Since we are talking about http and since we know Safari can open http links, the expectations is to receive a TRUE as result. The fact I receive a FALSE instead supports the fact the link can't be opened. Anywau, the point is that the question still remains: How to open the link I wrote in te question?

Comment: `canOpenURL` returns `true` for any `http` url I supply, including the example in your question.  My point is, however, that you know that http urls can be opened, so why are you even querying?  Just open the url.

Comment: That's the http link I need to open and canOpenURL returns false for it. The question is how to whitelist a link in that form

Comment: But why are you checking canOpenURL? Just open it.  CanOpenURL doesn’t do a reachability check. It is tells you whether there is an app that can handle the protocol. It doesn’t care about the rest of the URL path. You don’t need to whitelist full urls, only protocols

Comment: Forget canOpenURL. The point is the app is not able to open the URL in that format. Maybe because it's format has a query into it and Apple requires it to whitelist. How to whitelist a link with that format so that when DATA and USERNAME change the link can still be opened?

Comment: No, it is nothing to do with whitelisting. Are you generating a valid URL? Do you need to percent encode the URL parameters?  What happens when you try to open the URL?

Comment: The URL is valid as Safari can open it when copied and pasted in the URL bar. I have tried both with % and not % encoded and I can open it - nothing happens, including Safari is not called. The app calls Safari to open other URLs with no problems.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve] and/or a better example of your URL, since I cannot reproduce the symptoms you describe using the information you have provided.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is a good example: 
           https://www.agoda.com/partners/partnersearch.aspx?pcs=1&cid=1807795&hl=en&city=16594

Comment: I had no problem opening that URL using [this code](https://gist.github.com/paulw11/d02d2ca6dd77ed543d4e4cd16567eb02) in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. I'm using ObJC can't get it open:         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.agoda.com/partners/partnersearch.aspx?pcs=1&cid=1806795&hl=en&city=16594"]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];

Comment: That works for me; the only difference is it should be `options:@{:}`

Comment: You mean the ObjC code works as well for you on top of the Swift version? ObjC won't accept the {:}

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right.  That was a mistake on my part.  I have added by Objective C to the gist

Comment: Could you do me a favor and be so kind to check if the ObjC respective code you wrote in Swift works for you?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Both the swift and objective c code I used are in the gist I linked to above. Both pieces of code open the website in Safari

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice that you already updated the code with the ObjC version. I used your code and I can open the page, however I noticed the link is different from the one I gave you. How did you generate the one you have used? Thx

Comment: I think I probably opened the link in your comment and then copied the link from Safari, but I just tried it by copying the link directly from your comment and it worked too.

Comment: The one I posted doesn't work in my iPhone. Really weird. But I think I got a good solution by talking to you @Paulw11. I'll be happy to accept any answer you give me below just to thank you for your time. Thanks again!